# reading non-delimited integers

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a file in the format

```
11100000011111111
11100000011111111
11100000011111111
```

Each element is 1 digit.  Is there a good way to create a matrix using this as input?  Currently I'm reading each line as a string, casting it to a list and then storing it in a numpy array.

```
array = []
i_file = open(array_file, 'rb')
for line in i_file:
    data = list(line.strip().replace('?', '3'))
    array.append(data)
i_file.close()
array = np.array(array, dtype=np.int8)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I was wondering if there was a some way to read in the array using pandas.read_csv() or something of the sort.  I was unsure if I was missing something in the documentation that would let me do what I want to do with existing functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`read_fwf` is available for reading fixed-width files.  Below has an example of how you might use it in this case - `colspecs` is a list of the column specifications, as a tuple of [open, close) column positions.

```
In [55]: data = StringIO("""11100000011111111
    ...: 11100000011111111
    ...: 11100000011111111""")

In [58]: colspecs = [(n, n+1) for n in range(17)]


In [58]: df = pd.read_fwf(data, colspecs=colspecs, names=range(17))

In [58]: df
Out[58]: 
   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```